# Inserting values from datagridview into SQL Server database in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, datagrid

I have two tables in a SQL Server database, `product` and `innvoice`.

I am fetching selected data from table `product` and showing them in datagridview.

Now I want to store data from datagridview to table `innvoice`. This all operation takes on one button click.

Here is my code:

```
private void button5_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e) //add produt
{
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Persist Security Info=False;User ID=usait;password=123;Initial Catalog=givenget;Data Source=RXN-PC\ROSHAAN");
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT product.p_name,product.p_category, product.sale_price FROM product where p_code='" + textBox16.Text + "'", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView3.DataSource = dt;

        // here I want to insert values from datagridview3 to table innvoice.
}
```

Comment: You need an insert query. For goodness sake do a search on SO..

Comment: It's `Invoice` - one "n" only. And you should **stop** concatenating together your SQL statements -  that's just inviting hacker to exploit your SQL injection weakness! Use **parametrized queries** - always.

Comment: Instead of dataGridView, you can insert record from your dt.

Comment: I am not sure what the schema structure of your two tables looks like but you would be better off it you used an Id off the products table to act as a foreign key in your invoice table.  This way the invoice table just has the invoice specific information and you are not duplicating information all over the place.

Answer (score 2):

Please make a note.Using direct SQL query is not a good practise.

Hope this will help you.

```
 private void button5_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e) //add produt
    {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Persist Security Info=False;User ID=usait;password=123;Initial Catalog=givenget;Data Source=RXN-PC\ROSHAAN");
            Dataset ds=new Dataset();
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT product.p_name,product.p_category, product.sale_price FROM product where p_code='" + textBox16.Text + "'", con);
            da.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView3.DataSource = ds;

            //Code to insert values into Invoice
            for( i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
               sqlcommand cmd=new sqlcommand();
               cmd=new sqlcommand("insert into invoice(pname,pcategory,psaleprice) values('"+ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["product.p_name"].ToString()+"','"+ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["product.p_category"].ToString()+"','"+ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["product.sale_price"].ToString()+"')",con);
               cmd.executeNonquery();
            }
            con.close();

    }
```